# STS and Gradle Build Command Line Options

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Three years ago a question was asked on the Spring Forums about STS integration with Gradle command line options:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/109056-sts-and-gradle-build-command-line-options

It referenced the following two issues in the Gradle project's issue tracker. Those two issues were resolved in March and April of 2012. 
http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1691
http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1771

Since then has there been any updating of STS to support including Gradle command line build options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle Tooling API states that now they support most of the Gradle CLI from http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html (JavaDoc states: Only the build arguments that configure the build execution are supported)
I suppose the best way to see what's supported would be to install Gradle from this update site for example: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.6.2.RELEASE/e4.4 and try specifying the build arguments that you like and see if it works. 
Note, however, that the Gradle build launch UI has changed slightly. The tasks to tun are typed in with a help of content asisst, but you can't type in the gradle command line parameters there yet. They need to go in the application arguments section i think.

Comment: If you tell me where the application arguments section, or the place I type those CLI parameters, I will accept your answer. Is it in a run configuration or somewhere else? I tried the Tasks Quick Launcher and it doesn't even let simple commands like `-x test` be included with task names.

Comment: Gradle Build launch config dialog. Click on Arguments tab and enter those parameters in the "Program Args" text area.

Comment: As Alex mentioned arguments can be specified in launch config editor. They can also be specified in the "Gradle >> Arguments" preferences page. (Go to "Window >> Preferences >> Gradle >> Arguments". The arguments specified there are used for anything exeucted via Gradle from the IDE. The arguments specified in a Launch Config on the other hand are only used for that specific launch config.